# Updating a view in android

Tags: java, android, view, observable

For school I am trying to create a 2d based grid game where you can play agains a AI or another player. But we are having a issue with the AI. If you click on a empty tile in our grid a method will trigger called onEmptyTileClicked with a X and Y coordinate of the tile. We use this method to place stones on the field (each player has its own stone so lets say you are blue and the AI is yellow).

You can see a basic example here:

```
public void onEmptyTileClicked(int x, int y) {
        GameBoard board = getGameBoard();
        int counter = 0;
        //check if the blue player needs to set or the yellow
        if (player1) {

            //sets the amount of diamonds that will be taken over in the var counter, if this is bigger than 0 we can place it
            counter = board.countTakeovers(x,y, true);
            if (counter > 0) {
                //add the diamond to the board
                board.addGameObject(new Blue(), x, y);

                //add a message in logcat and in the statistic log
                Log.d("CoolGameBoard", "Adding blue diamond");  
                activity.updateStatisticLog(activity.getString(R.string.blue_placed)+" "+(x+1)+", "+(y+1)+ " + " + counter + " " + activity.getString(R.string.conquered)); 

                //change all the diamonds that are taken over with this set
                board.takeover(x,y,true);

                //turn is over give the other player a turn and update the gameboard
                setDone();

            } else {

                //player clicked a wrong point, give them a error message
                Log.d("CoolGameBoard", "Can't place the blue diamond at this location.");
                activity.updateStatisticLog(activity.getString(R.string.cant_blue) + " "+(x+1)+", "+(y+1)); 
            }

        } else {

            counter = board.countTakeovers(x,y,false);
            if (counter > 0) {
                board.addGameObject(new Yellow(), x, y);
                Log.d("CoolGameBoard", "Adding yellow diamond");                
                activity.updateStatisticLog(activity.getString(R.string.yellow_placed)+" "+(x+1)+", "+(y+1)+ " + " + counter + " " + activity.getString(R.string.conquered));                                   
                board.takeover(x,y,false);              
                setDone();
            } else {
                Log.d("CoolGameBoard", "Can't place the yellow diamond at this location.");
                activity.updateStatisticLog(activity.getString(R.string.cant_yellow) + " "+(x+1)+", "+(y+1));       
            }
        }
    }
```

If a player placed a stone the setDone() method will be called to handle some visual stuff like updateing the gameboard and some other stuff. This method looks like this:

```
public void setDone() {
    GameBoard board = getGameBoard();
    player1 = !player1;

    activity.updateBeurt(player1);
    activity.updateBlueDiamonds(board.countBlueDiamonds());
    activity.updateYellowDiamonds(board.countYellowDiamonds());
    board.updateView();

    if (board.possibilities(player1) == 0) {
        player1 = !player1;
        activity.updateBeurt(player1);
        if (board.possibilities(player1) == 0) {
            Log.d("FDGame","GAME OVER!!");
            activity.gameOver();
        }
    }

    if(AI && !player1){
        computerPlayer.move();
    }
}
```

As you can see at the end of this method if the boolean AI is set to true we will call the computerPlayer.move(); method which will basicially let the AI set a new stone which we once again use the onEmtpyTileClicked() method for.

We wanted to have a sleep between the set you made as a player and the set your AI does else you won't see the chances the AI makes to the field. However the method board.updateView() seems to be executed at the end of the whole onEmtpyTileClicked() loop. this method looks like this:

```
public void updateView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Updating game view");

    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
```

Could someone maybe explain why the notifyObservers() only triggers while a certain thread seems to be done? Because if we add a sleep before the AI makes a move it will just look like nothing is placed for a second and then both of the stones are placed resulting in the same as before with just a delay before it all happends.

Comment: If you add a sleep before AI makes a move, do you still make the changes of the UI on the UI-Thread?

Comment: The gameboard view (the UI of the board) is a Observer from the Observerable where the updateView() method is in. Does this answer your question? I dont really understand what you mean with the ui on the ui-thread..

Comment: If you inserst a sleep. It will probably look like this: `new Thread(){Thread.sleep(someTime); computerPlayer.move()}.start();`. Am I right? If so, then `notifyObservers();` is not called on UI-Thread (since you started a new thread). And you cannot update the view from a non-UI-Thread. On most devices you will get an exception, but I have experienced that on some devices, you don't get an exception, nothing happens.